# Im sending emails using phpmailer class with sucess, but my emails content appears minimized

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I have a form to send an email where I need to write a subject in my input.

Then I have a sql select statment to chosse an email to send email.

Then I have a message saying that this email is for test purposes and if user wants dont want to receive more emails I provide a link that when user clicks, he can remove his email from database.

Im already sending emails with sucess, **but Im having always a problem**: my sent emails appears minimized, with this icon:
[image]

And I need to click in this button to see email content.

Do you know why this can be happening??

**This is an excerpt from my php code:**

```
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$email  = $sqlResult['email'];

$msg = '<p style="font:15px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#000;">This is an email for test.</p><p style="font:15px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#000">You can click in this link below to dont receive more emails from us.</p><a href="http://localhost/website/template/remove.php?email='.$email.'">Remove</a><p style="font:15px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#555;">Best Regards</p>';

sendMail($subject,$msg,MAILUSER,SITENAME,$email,'');
```

**This is my function:**

```
function sendMail($subject,$message,$from,$namefrom,$to,$nameto,$reply = NULL, $replyName = NULL){
    require_once('mail/class.phpmailer.php'); 
    $mail = new PHPMailer(); 
    $mail->IsSMTP(); 
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true; 
    $mail->IsHTML(true);
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls"; 
    $mail->Host = MAILHOST; 
    $mail->Port = MAILPORT; 
    $mail->Username = MAILUSER; 
    $mail->Password = MAILPASS; 
    $mail->From = utf8_decode($from); 
    $mail->FromName = utf8_decode($namefrom); 

    if($reply != NULL){
        $mail->AddReplyTo(utf8_decode($reply),utf8_decode($replyName)); 
    }

    $mail->Subject = utf8_decode($subject); 
    $mail->Body = utf8_decode($message); 
    $mail->AddAddress(utf8_decode($to),utf8_decode($nameto)); 

    if($mail->Send()){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you see if you do "View Source" of the email?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Im seeing my email content and before my email content I have this code in my button/icon to show email content: <div id=":40" class="ajR" role="button" tabindex="0" data-tooltip="Show cut content" aria-label="Show cut content"><img class="ajT" src="//ssl.gstatic.com/ui/v1/icons/mail/images/cleardot.gif"></div>

Comment: Looks like PHPMailer is adding all that stuff when you set `IsHTML(true)`. Check its documentation to see if you can control it.

Comment: IsHTML doesn't add any content, it just sets the MIME type. Why are you doing all the `utf8_decodes`? PHPMailer works fine with UTF-8, though you do need to tell it since it defaults to ISO8859-1. You should also use the autoloader instead of requiring the class manually. For more diagnostics, you should paste the source of the received message here.

Answer (score 0):

I bet you are reading emails with *GMail*. The icon you posted is automatically added by *GMail* whenever it encounters double dashes (and possibly other combinations I don't know), so your problem is likely not related to your PHP code, but to the content of `$message`. Try to send yourself an email with this body:

```
This message is shown.
-- 
This is considered a signature by GMail, so it will be smartly hidden.
```

I hate smart programs...